# automatically track user location in a java web application

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

How to automatically track user location in a java webapplication?

I dunt want to take inputs like country city from  user. 
Could anyone also let know how to use **maxmind api**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of options for Geolocating a user on a web app.

One of the most used can be, javascript based geolocation.

http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/

You can use it on your *.jsp page to geolocate the user and send to the servlet the info you want to save like coordinates.

Hope it helps, if you want another aproach just make me know.

Comment: is maxminds approach a good one but  dunt know how to use it in my java portal application any tutorials on how to integrate maxmind with java'

Comment: Here you have the Maxmind api for Java and other lenguages. You need to implement a way to make your app able to talk with the Maxmind java api.
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable#Java-8 :)